# Audio programming and tone synthesis

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing

I am mostly a business programmer and I've not done anything in audio programming since the ZX Spectrum so I'm not sure how to even ask this question correctly.

I just need some pointers in the right direction with regards to writing (Android in this case, but it is really a general question) applications which deal with audio such as a Tone Matrix.

Are they based on generating lots of samples or are the tones generated on the fly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the answer here: [Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)

Answer (score 1):

Any mixture of both.

Interesting audio-related DSP discussions happen on the forums at http://www.kvraudio.com.

Answer (score 1):

Android provides two ways to perform sound output.

One is using AudioTrack class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

It's method write, allowes to output PCM data. 
AudioTrack can be used in streaming and static modes.

Another way is to use Android Native Development Kit, and OpenSL ES.