# Generate arbitrary beep in Android

Tags: android, audio

as far as I know, there is no simple way in Android to generate a beep (equivalent to Console.Beep(int frequency, int length) in .NET). The only one that looked promising - `ToneGenerator` class, can generate only a limited selection of tones.

Do I have to generate a waveform by hand, push its data to AudioTrack and play it or is there a library or open source code that does it?

Comment: I am in the same crossroads, which way did you take?

Comment: I froze the project and focused on another, until there's time to do more research on this subject

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661444/how-to-play-different-frequeny-sound-in-android) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android) and [Generate And Play A Tone In Android](http://marblemice.blogspot.com/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same. Found on this very site an answer:

1. Calculate numbers for a waveform with a given frequency
2. Convert the resulting array to PCM format
3. Feed AudioTrack to play it back.

That's a good start.

I don't have the URL but you will find the code easily in FAQ looking for someone asking for "...arbitrary frequency"