# How to play different frequeny sound in android?

Tags: android, audio

HI,

I want to create a animal repeller application.I'm new bie to android.I want to play different  frequency sound to repel the animal,but I'm not clear how to play .please help me out .

Thanx in advance.
Praween.

Comment: 17 questions and not a single answer accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a ToneGenerator:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html

Allows you to create tones to you specific needs, includes controlls for frequency, length of tone, so on.

Read up on the class and find the best way to do what you want it to do.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think this is correct. From reading the reference, ToneGenerator plays DTMF tones, not tones of a specified frequency. This answer states that ToneGenerator contains a control for frequency, but as far as I can tell it does not.