# Android - how to create music note sound?

Tags: android, audio

Folks,

In my android app, I need to display a musical instrument such that the user (mostly children) could press a key and I play the music note through the speaker.

I am trying to understand what it takes to generate a music note under Android. The examples on sound that I saw mostly use MediaPlayer or SoundPlayer to play media files. I am looking for sending a specific tone with duration to the speaker.

I would appreciate your help in pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 4):

Check out this question for 1 possible implementation of Tone Generating.

[Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)