# Pure Tones in Android

Tags: java, android, audio

Is there any way to generate and play pure tones in Android? I know there isn't any MIDI support in Android at the moment so I was wondering if there were any third party libraries for doing it?

Comment: This Stack Overflow question might be what you are looking for...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, MediaPlayer actually will play MIDI files. As for generating the tones, the only library I know of is a general MIDI library, which you can probably use to create MIDI files on-the-fly and hand off to MediaPlayer for playback.

http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows how to use the AudioTrack api and has an example of pushing a basic sine wav to it.

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=228