# Record Sound And play Modulated Sound In Android?

Tags: android, audio, service, record

Hello Am Currently Doing An App Related To Sound Modulation I need to know How to Record A sound And Modulate The Recorded Sound in Another Voice . Like Talking Tom Cat Application. i had Tried A solution From Stack over flow [From HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)

And From Another Blog [Blog Address](http://marblemice.blogspot.in/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html)

But i did not get Any idea.Can Any one please Give me Some Ideas Or Solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at last i have find the solution this may help some one

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/implement-voice-changer-by-changing.html

code

```
public class Sound_modActivity extends Activity {

 Integer[] freqset = {11025, 16000, 22050, 44100};
 private ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter;

 Spinner spFrequency;
 Button startRec, stopRec, playBack;

 Boolean recording;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startrec);
    stopRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stoprec);
    playBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playback);

    startRec.setOnClickListener(startRecOnClickListener);
    stopRec.setOnClickListener(stopRecOnClickListener);
    playBack.setOnClickListener(playBackOnClickListener);

    spFrequency = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.frequency);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, freqset);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

   OnClickListener startRecOnClickListener
= new OnClickListener(){


  public void onClick(View arg0) {

  Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){


public void run() {
 recording = true;
 startRecord();
  }

  });

   recordThread.start();

  }};

 OnClickListener stopRecOnClickListener
 = new OnClickListener(){


 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 recording = false;
 }};

 OnClickListener playBackOnClickListener
 = new OnClickListener(){


public void onClick(View v) {
playRecord();
}

};

 private void startRecord(){

 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm"); 

 int sampleFreq = (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

 try {
   file.createNewFile();

  OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
 BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

  int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleFreq, 
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

  short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

  AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
 sampleFreq,
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
 minBufferSize);

  audioRecord.startRecording();

  while(recording){
  int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
 dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
   }
  }

  audioRecord.stop();
  dataOutputStream.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }

 void playRecord(){

 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

    int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

  int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
  short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

  try {
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

int i = 0;
while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
 audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
i++;
}

 dataInputStream.close();

 int sampleFreq = (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

 AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
 AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
 sampleFreq,
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
 bufferSizeInBytes,
 AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

audioTrack.play();
audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
 }

}
```

Comment: You might want to answer the question here, not just tell us that you know the answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.