# What is AudioFlinger and why does it fail TONE_PROP_ACK?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, dtmf, audioflinger

In my application I issue the following statement:

```
toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_ACK, 600);
```

Which works very well on a cheap LG LS670 running Android 2.3.3 but doesn't sound at all on all other phones I have, ranging from Android 2.2.1 to Android 2.3.4.

So I know the OS version doesn't play a role here (I also verified in the documentation that it has been supported since API 1).

Also, both Ringer volume and Media volume are set to maximum and toneGenerator is initialized with:

```
toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1, 100);
```

And I verified that `Settings.System.DTMF_TONE_WHEN_DIALING` is set to 1.

Baffled by this inconsistent behavior (across different phones), I examined the system logs when this happens and the only suspicious difference I have been able to find is that the phones who **fail** to sound `TONE_PROP_ACK` have this line in their log:

```
AudioFlinger    setParameters(): io 25, keyvalue routing=0, tid 155, calling tid 121
```

What is the purpose of [AudioFlinger](http://androidaudio.blogspot.com/2010/06/so-what-is-audioflinger.html) and what could be its connection to muting `TONE_PROP_ACK`?

Any [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android) how to fix my code so that that TONE_PROP_ACK always sounds, regardless of phone model?

Comment: Audio flinger is the system component which manages the audio from android userpsace before handing it off to the kernel driver.  Are you able to get sound from any of the tone functions?  Did you see the part in the API docs about the audio routing being variable?  What are you really trying to accomplish anyway - you know these tones do not go through the call uplink, right?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, I know these tones do not go through the call uplink. This is actually my preferred behavior as I am only trying to give an audible cue (it doesn't have to be DTMF). I am able to get sound from the tone functions when I use the phone's dialing activity. Can you elaborate on "the audio routing being variable"? Where do I find that part in the API docs? Direct URL would be super. Thanks +1.

Comment: `routing=0` for `io 25` means that the AudioFlinger is telling a particular audio stream (I'm guessing an AudioStreamOut in this case) that it should route to "nowhere". How the audio HAL will handle that is implementation-specific - so it might e.g. leave the routing for that stream unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to generate the tone in something like Audacity and play it through SoundPool or the api of your choice.

According to the Android docs ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_ACK is:

1200Hz, 100ms ON, 100ms OFF 2 bursts

If you choose SoundPool, I suggest saving in ogg file format and loop the tone until complete. This while provide seamless audio with a very small clip and not using a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

The parsing/decoding is handled by Stage fright, which is used by the
media player service. The decoded data is written to an Audio Track
through an Audio Sink, and the tracks are then mixed by the
Audio Flinger's mixer thread(s) and written to an output stream
(Audio Hardware). The output stream object fills up its own buffer(s)
and then writes the data to the PCM output device file (which may or
may not be an ALSA driver).