# android audio track wont output beyond a certain frequency

Tags: android, signals, generator, audiotrack

I have create an app for android that creates and stores a single tone, then plays it back utilizing android audio track class. Here's the issue: on my phone I can only play tones up to  a frequency of about 11kHz, and on a virtual phone run from my PC (same exact code) I can get frequencies up to about 14kHz. What could cause this cutoff?

Using a tone generator app from the market, my phone can produce up to 20kHz signals, so I know it is not a hardware issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you provide some of the code for how you're generating the tone.

For audio stuff, you should go here http://music.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/andraudio and signup then ask there. There's a great community of Android developers for that list all dedicated to audio development.

Also, self-promotion, I run a forum website (relatively new and needing updates) and I plan to add an Android Audio forum on it once I get enough interested folks. If you're interested, sign up [here](http://forum.jakar.co/and-audio/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I have a chance I will post my code and post any results from those websites you offered.

Comment: For the 1st site (music.columbia.edu) you sign up then you actually email andraudio@music.columbia.edu to ask the members of the list your question. The 2nd site (my self-promotion) is currently worthless because I haven't launched an Android audio forum as of yet. That would be for potential future help you need.

Comment: Just to update, I fixed the issue by rewriting parts of my code that I have not posted. Just as a warning to others that are trying to develop some sort of function generator, there's a code that is floating around the internet (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android) that I've seen on many posts for generating a signal, this code is very buggy despite it working in some instances.