# android as a ultrasonic sound emitter and receiver

Tags: android, audio

I want one of my android phones to emit sounds that are unhearable by human, and the other to listen to it and analyse frequency and so on.
Is it even possible?

And my next question is - can mic support two channels? I want to analyse if the sound comes from the left of my device or right of it. Is it possible?

Comment: Android is just the operating system, probably there are different hardware limitations on each device.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the phones can reproduce sounds over 16KHz. Also the microphone won't be able to record those kind of frequencies as well.

For your second question, if your device has stereo microphone it is possible, you can find more about this on the following link: http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-note/536841-stereo-audiorecord.html.

Comment: Do you know any site whare I can see if my phone has stereo microphone?

Comment: You can check the device (no, i don't know any websites that could share this informations - [www.gsmarena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com) does not show this kind of characteristics). A stereo microphone consists basically of two separated microphones.

Answer (score 2):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731075/1198897)

Change the frequency to beyond 20000 and see if you can get what you want.