# Generate Sine Tone with sweep - Android

Tags: java, android, trigonometry

I am trying to generate sine tone with sweep. I am using the code below which i got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456087/how-do-i-generate-a-sine-sweep-in-java-android). The problem is, i can hear sound that is above 200Hz but i cannot hear tone that is below 200Hz (like 20hz or 50Hz). 
Please help me to generate accurate sine tone.

```
private final int sampleRate = 44100;              


public void generateTone(double startFreq, double endFreq, float duration)
{
    double dnumSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    dnumSamples = Math.ceil(dnumSamples);
    numSamples = (int) dnumSamples;
    double sample[] = new double[numSamples];

    double currentFreq = 0,numerator;

    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        numerator = (double) i / (double) numSamples;
        currentFreq = startFreq + (numerator * (endFreq - startFreq))/2;
        if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
            Log.e("Current Freq:", String.format("Freq is:  %f at loop %d of %d", currentFreq, i, numSamples));
        }
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / currentFreq));
    }

    generatedSnd = new byte[2 * numSamples];
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will be more robust if you keep track of the current position in the sine wave, and increment it based on the current frequency, instead of calculating the position each sample relative to the starting position.

```
double currentPos = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
    numerator = (double) i / (double) numSamples;
    currentFreq = startFreq + (numerator * (endFreq - startFreq))/2;
    if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
        Log.e("Current Freq:", String.format("Freq is:  %f at loop %d of %d", currentFreq, i, numSamples));
    }
    currentPos += 2 * Math.PI * (currentFreq / sampleRate);
    sample[i] = Math.sin(currentPos);
}
```

This avoids a problem with an decrease in the frequency potentially causing the current position to move backwards.

If you want the tone to fade in over a certain number of samples you can add this code:

```
int fadeInSamples = 5000;
double fadeIn = (i < fadeInSamples) ? (double)i / (double)fadeInSamples : 1.0;

sample[i] = Math.sin(currentPos) * fadeIn;
```

Comment: now i can hear the tone.. but there is an annoying beep when tone starts. I am using AudioTrack to play this tone

Comment: `audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, (int)numSamples*2,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

            audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);     // Load the track
            audioTrack.play();                                          // Play the track`

Comment: I'm not sure what causes that, it might be the discontinuity when the tone starts. I've added some code to do a fade-in that hopefully masks it.