# Generate sweep tone starting from one frequency to another frequency with same increment in frequency value

Tags: java, android

I want the code for sine sweep tone generation from one frequency to another frequency, but the change in frequency should be same in every incrementation in frequency value. The tone speed should be adjusted based on duration

I tried few StackOverflow codes, they are great
but I m not satisfied with speed on tone incrementation.

[How do I generate a Sine Sweep in Java (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456087/how-do-i-generate-a-sine-sweep-in-java-android)

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink
actually, I worked on tone generation with a single frequency
now started with sweep tone
so trying out codes