# How to generate a squared wave in Android during an infinite time?

Tags: android, audio, waveform

I need to generate a squared wave in Android and I was wondering where i could get information to build a app doing that, I dont want only the answer but also a place where i could easily understand the code.

Comment: What have you searched for so far?

Comment: I've seen hwo to build some sine waves but the problem is that i lack knowledge to understand most of the procedure

Comment: I want something similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android

But that plays during an infinite time and generates a square wave instead of sine one