# Transfer bytes array via inaudible sound waves in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, data-transfer

I want to implements this:
http://rnd.azoft.com/mobile-app-transering-data-using-ultrasound/
in an Android App.

I implemented the design of the App in Android Studio and the last thing that I need to implements its the "Transfer Button" in other words -
I need to convert a byte array like [1,0,0,1,0,1,0] to inaudible sound waves
and receive in another mobile the sound and convert the sound to byte array 
[1,0,0,1,0,1,0] back.

where to start?
thank a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android http://buildsmartrobots.ning.com/profiles/blogs/generating-audio-tones-using-android http://nathanbelue.blogspot.com/2013/01/playing-pitch-in-android-app-with.html

Comment: tnx man for your helping
but my real problem is:
"and receive in another mobile the sound and convert the sound to byte array [1,0,0,1,0,1,0] back"

in another word the app open in two mobiles
i want to write string of bytes like 1010101000
and receive this string in the second mobile

Comment: You will need to use `AudioRecord` and largely reverse the process, I imagine.

Comment: for iOS but same idea: https://github.com/applidium/AudioModem. For an overview of the way it works: http://applidium.com/en/news/data_transfer_through_sound/

Comment: its not helped me...

Comment: someone help???
js can help me too and c#

Comment: Have you done this ??