# Generate and play sound dynamically (from frequency/amplitude data)

Tags: java, android, audio

So I'm trying to find out if its possible to create some sound waves that I can then manipulate using java, more specifically for the android platform. The Idea is to get integer values and using that, dynamically change pitch/pulse based on user input. I've looked into the soundpool class and it seems that that only handles sampled audio, I'm wondering if there is any way to actually generate it using code.

I'm assuming that if so, each wave generated would have to use it's own thread in order to manipulate them independently. Can someone confirm this?

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this question whose highest voted answer is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. In any case, here's the link for reference:

[Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)