# How to play a single frequency tone on android device?

Tags: android

I'm new in android development. I'm now trying to play a single tone on a specific frequency on my cell phone. I didn't find any method that could play a specific tone. For example, only play a tone on 400Hz.
Does anyone help me to find some method? Thank you.

PS:Some friends mentioned me that this question is same with another question. But after I test that code I got three frequencies.[here is the spectrum I got from that question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgNQq.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android

Comment: I've been tried that before, but what I achieved is I could see two more tones play together with the frequency I want to play.

Answer (score 0):

There are  a utility software under linux named 'sox' which can generate any single frequency you wanted.
for example: 
sox -r 44100 -n 5.wav synth 60 sine 20
this command can generate a file named 5.wav, which is 20Hz sine wave with sample rate 44.1k and lasting 60 seconds.
you can try android version:
https://github.com/Kyborg2011/SoxPlaye