# Generating sound from musical note android

Tags: android, audio, key, frequency, tone-generator

Good evening, is there a way to generate the 88 piano key sounds by inputting their freq and duration? I've seen this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)  that may be similar to what I am finding but whenever i change the value of the frequency because I want to play the 4th key on the keyboard I doesn't sound anything at all. is there any alternative to play all the 88 keys in the keyboard by inputting the specific duration of the note and frequency?? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The link you provided dealt with something simmilar in later answers and comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)

Comment: @LudovitMydla but have you ever tried that block of code??

Comment: also is there a third party application that can generate the sound and create a midi file or mp3 file??