# Android Kotlin - Generate Tone/Beep of Particular Frequency

Tags: android, kotlin, frequency, beep

I am facing an issue regarding playing the tone on a particular frequency.
I used the `ToneGenerator` class as instructed by ChatGPT. I am unable to play it on a specific frequency.

I tried this:

```
private val generator = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 100)

fun Beep(frequency: Float) {
generator.startTone(ToneManager.TONE_DTMF_0, 1000, 200) // Desired Frequency: 200
}
```

But it seems the 3rd parameter doesn't exist now. Is it possible to use the same tone generator to play any frequency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android)

Comment: Careful with ChatGPT--it very confidently tells you completely false information like this. A 3rd parameter has *never* existed for this class. ToneGenerator cannot play tones at arbitrary frequencies.